# Null Pointer Exception in Servlet view.forward(request, response) method

Tags: servlets

Javascript in the File main.jsp

```
    <script>
        var form = null;
        var item = null;
        window.onload = init;
        function init(){
            form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];                    
            item = document.getElementById("selectedItem"); 

        }
        function handleCellClick(e)
        {
            item.value = e.innerHTML;
            alert(item.value);
            form.submit();
        }
    </script>
```

and main.jsp file contains

```
<body>
        <ul id="menuList">
            <li class="mainMenuItem">Master</li>
            <li class="subMenuItem clickCell" onClick="handleCellClick(this)">Cashier Info.</li>
            <li class="subMenuItem">Product Info.</li>
            <li class="subMenuItem">Price list Info.</li>
            <li class="subMenuItem">Agent Info</li>
        <li class="mainMenuItem">Transaction</li>
            <li class="subMenuItem">Invoice Creation</li>
            <li class="subMenuItem">Invoice Correction</li>
            <li class="subMenuItem">Change Invoice Date</li>
        <li class="mainMenuItem">Report</li>
            <li class="subMenuItem">Daily Sale Report</li>
            <li class="subMenuItem">Trucksheet</li>
            <li class="subMenuItem">Agent Sale Report</li>
        <li class="mainMenuItem">Logoff</li>
    </ul>
    <form action="<c:url value='Main.do' />">
        <input id="selectedItem" name="selectedItem" type="hidden" />
    </form>
</body>
```

and Servlet contains

```
public class MainProgram extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String jsp =null;
    String selectedItem = request.getParameter("selectedItem");



    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if(session==null){
        jsp = "login.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(jsp);
        view.forward(request, response);
    }else{
        jsp = "user_info.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(jsp);
        view.forward(request, response);     // this line gives NullPointerException
    }
}

public void doPost (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String userName = request.getParameter("txtUserName");  
        String jsp = null;                      //clickme page

        if(userName.equals("Admin") || userName.equals("Operator") || userName.equals("Guest")){
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("regUser", userName);
            jsp = "main.jsp";
        }else{
            jsp = "login.jsp";      
        }
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(jsp);
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

After login and submit it goes to main.jsp
when i click on Cashier Info it alerts submit execute servlet
but servlet gives NullPointerException at last line line 
and that line contains

```
            view.forward(request, response);
```

HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NullPointerException
....
....
com.program.web.MainProgram.doGet(MainProgram.java:31)

I am stopped now to think
I can't get why this is so

Please guide on this!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have posted to `.../Main.do` and you try to get dispacher for servlet at `main.jsp`. The server obeys and looks for the servlet at `.../Main.do/main.jsp` :-(

I assume it finds nothing and `view` is null ...

**A relative URL is a constant danger**, it may be used, but *carefully*.

(But +1 for directly giving all relevant info ...)